# Why is my iframe hiding my dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I have searched thoroughly for an answer to this, but the answers I have found here will not seem to work for me...

I have a dropdown menu that is being hidden by a table containing an `iframe`.  I have included the code below.

How can I make the menu display on top of the table containing the `iframe`?

I have tried the z-index solutions and they did not work.  I have also tried wmode="transport" within the iframe tag, and that did not work.

`CSS` for menu:

```
div.crm_menu {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
font: bold 14px Verdana ;
text-align: left;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 4px 5px 0;
position: absolute;
top : 120px;
list-style: none;
float: left;
}
ul li {
font: bold 14px/18px Verdana ;
display: inline;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
padding: 15px 20px;
background: #a4b8c3;
cursor: pointer;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
ul li:hover {
background: #1d4f6a;
color: white;
}
ul li ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 47px;
left: 0;
width: 250px;
box-shadow: none;
display: none;
opacity: 0;
visibility: visible;
float: left;
}
ul li ul li {
background: #1d4f6a;
width: 250px;
display: inline-block;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
ul li ul li:hover { 
background: #93a5af;
color: black;
}
ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

HTML for table with iframe:

```
<table border="0" height="700" width="100%">`

<tr>

<td>

<iframe src="http://www.idissys.com/download/it_blog.pdf?wmode=transparent" height="700" width="100%" wmode="transparent" style="overflow:scroll;"></iframe>

</td>
</tr>
```

`</table>`

Comment: fiddle would be good for that case

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you please link a jsfiddle or a stack-snippet with your question, so we can see exactly what you are seeing?

Comment: jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/mjcuccia/cfrbvx5L/

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index property in the container of the menu, you can set the z-index of the table to 1 for example and the z-index of the menu to 2.

See:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: the menu is inside a table which is inside of another table for positioning.  Should I set the z-index on the immediate containing table or the outer table?  also, should I simply use position: static so that the position of my containing tables won't really change?

Comment: I tried z-index on the immediate containing table and the table containing the iframe, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "z-index" property for the table + menu. z-index handles the 'z' positon of an element. z-index also only works combined with the 'position' property. The higher the number the higher the element will be (more in front).

Code update:

Example:

```
<center style="position:relative;z-index:10;">...

<center style="position:relative;z-index:0;">...
```

For more information check the css-tricks article: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: the menu is inside a table which is inside of another table for positioning. Should I set the z-index on the immediate containing table or the outer table? also, should I simply use position: static so that the position of my containing tables won't really change?

Comment: I tried z-index on the immediate containing table and the table containing the iframe, and it did not work.

Comment: Hey Michael, i just checked your jsfiddle and found the solution. You have to apply the z-index to your <center> tags (you have two of them), because z-index applies to the parent element, in this case the first element is center. I updated the code above. If it works, please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: that did not work. the .pdf in the iframe still shows in front of the list menu.

Answer (score 0):

Per your JSfiddle, set the containing center tags for your menu and iframe to `position: relative;` and give the first center tag (the one containing your menu) `z-index: 2`.

Also, the center tag is deprecated. You may want to replace them with div tags. Then again, this [plucky little start-up](https://www.google.com/) uses center tags on their home page, so who am I to judge?

Comment: that did not work.  the .pdf in the iframe still shows in front of the list menu.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Shambolaz/cfrbvx5L/10/

This is based off your JSfiddle, I added the relevant CSS fix at the bottom of the CSS pane in the fiddle.

Let me know if that doesn't work.